# Run query_posts if SESSION is empty?

Tags: posts, query, session

I am having trouble running query_posts when my page loads for the first time, i.e Session is empty.

When the page loads for the first time and the SESSION is empty, the following code runs:

```
    <?php
    $id = 106;
  if ((empty($_SESSION['r1']))){            
            echo "This Line Prints";
            query_posts("cat=-.'$id'&".$query_string);
            wp_reset_query();
                echo "This Line also Prints";
        }
    ?>
```

The two statements mentioned in the above code are printing but the query_posts is not running here. However when I am running it outside the session it is working fine :S
How can I run this query_posts if the Session is empty? Why doesn't this code  work?

Comment: You're calling `wp_reset_query()` right after you run `query_posts()`; so how do you *know* that `query_posts()` **isn't** running, and simply being *reset*?

Comment: I've already checked that without calling wp_reset_query() & it doesn't work either

Comment: where are you setting `$id`? also- remove the dot and single quotes around $id.

Comment: this is not the issue either, as if i replace $id with the constant category ID it doesn't work either , btw $id is declared right above this code

Comment: We need to see actual code that you're using, not test code.

Comment: this is the actual code not a test code , the only thing missing is $id which i've added in my post , thnkyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( empty($_SESSION['r1']) ) {
    global $query_string;         
    query_posts($query_string . "&cat=-" . $id);
}
```

This should work, depending on $id is set.